# Cloud functions for firebase - remove value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to delete a specific child in my database using a cloud function.
Basic function setup is ok, so I´ll only include the ref part. In this case I just want to remove the Pineapple from the "fruits".

My fruit with the FRUITID "Pineapple" is a child of "fruits" and has different child values. Besides, there are also different fruits under "fruits":

```
let fruitID = "Pineapple";
let ref = admin.database().ref("data").child("fruits").child(fruitID);
//ref.removeVal(); -> Which code to use?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using the Admin SDK, `ref.remove()` should do the trick. The documentation for deleting values is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data.